# How to left-align text in a centered context

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I can guess that I am missing something in here. Still can't `left-align` text in a `centered div`

here is a mimic sample of my final work:

```
<div class="grid-row">
        <img src="http://www.fununlimitedsports.com/wp-content/images/istockSUP.jpg" />
        <div class="profile-info">
            <div class="name"><a href="#">STUDENT NAME '14</a></div>
            <div class="occupation">Toured nationally with “West Side Story”</div>
            <div class="major">MAJOR: MUSIC THEATRE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
 .grid-row {
        max-width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid green;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

How to keep the `profile-info` div centered inside the `grid-row` and maintain a `left-aligned` text at the same time for it's content?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guW7Q/)

*the image used  is a random img from google*

Edit:
I need the div `profile-info` to still be in the middle of the `grid-row` and to `left-align` its text

Comment: Are you under the impression that the `text-align: center;` rule on `.grid-row` is centering the `.profile-info` div? Because that's not how it's working.

Comment: Nope, I know that the `margin` for its parent does.

Comment: The `margin` rule on `.grid-row` is centering `.grid-row`. It does nothing for the placement of `.profile-info` within `.grid-row`.

Comment: Well, yeah. I thought you are talking about centering the entire thing on the screen. I got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.grid-row {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align:center;
}

.profile-info {
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div clas="grid-row">
  <div class="profile-info">
    info
  </div>
</div>
```

I've edited your fiddle.

Comment: exactly, thanks. the `margin 0 auto` is what was missing

Comment: The `!important` is unnecessary.

Comment: This doesn't work. I pasted the code in the fiddle and the text is left-aligned but *not* centered.

Comment: The text should be left aligned inside a centered container. Check the snippet and see that it does work.

Answer (score 3):

This centers the text box (`margin: 0 auto;`) and this aligns the text left (`text-align:left;`). Works only if the box is limited in width (for example `width:300px;`).

```
.profile-info {    
   border:1px solid gray;
   text-align:left;
   width:300px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```